# Java nashorn compare if a java objects is of a certain java type

Tags: java, nashorn

I am using instanceof but it is currently not working as I expect it. I have a variable I retrieve from my java code inside my script. Let's call this variable myObject which is the instance of a MyObject class, as you would expect.

```
if (myObject instanceof Java.type("MyObject")) {
    //The check doesn't pass; the code here doesn't execute
}
```

I could only find vague information on the net about this. What is the definite way of checking if myObject is an instance of the MyObject class as I would easily do in Java?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `MyObject` a type you know at compile time? Then `myObject instanceof MyObject` would do the trick.

Comment: Do you mean that I register the class to the nashorn script engine? In any way, I don't think it is known.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you have should work, (with fully qualified class names, of course). E.g. this definitely works:

```
jjs> var x = new java.util.BitSet()
jjs> x instanceof Java.type("java.util.BitSet") 
true
```

Note: `java.util.BitSet` and `Java.type("java.util.BitSet")` are interchangeable, I just used both to illustrate that no matter how you construct the object, the result should be the same.